# C# - Change a format of string to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, string-formatting

I have a problem when I get datetime form mysql to store in datatable. However, I got a string like `9/1/2017 12:00:00 AM`. I want to show it only in date format like `01/09/2017`.

What is the fastest way to change a string like `9/1/2017 12:00:00 AM` to date `01/09/2017` in C#?

Comment: stored as datetime  or string?

Comment: Do something like this: `DateTime.ParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` and then `newdate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I tried it but It showed the error `Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`. Because my string is like `M/d/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy` and the exact format I want is `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: I stored it as date format but when I read it from dataTable, I got a string like  `9/1/2017 12:00:00 AM`. This is the code: `string dateMade = dTable.Rows[i]["NgayChup"].ToString();`

Comment: If you're sure the DB column contains DateTime value, use `string dateMade = ((DateTime)dTable.Rows[i]["NgayChup"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`. Otherwise using `DateTime.ParseExact` and `ToString` like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse("9/1/2017 12:00:00 AM");
var str = dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: daaangerous, because it will use current culture so it can be either 9 Jan or 1 of Sep :)

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @Tetsuya Yamamoto and @Rawitas Krungkaew. Both your answers are solutions of this problem:
Solution 1:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse("9/1/2017 12:00:00 AM");
var str = dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Solution 2:

```
string dateMade = ((DateTime)dTable.Rows[i]["NgayChup"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"‌​)
```